# Identifying latest sequence of steps in SQL table

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a SQL table which contains timestamped sequences of steps, for two different recipes. I'm trying to figure out **a way of identifying the "current" or "latest" recipe**. My source table looks a bit like this:

| recipe | timestamp | step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:55 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:50 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:45 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:40 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:35 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:30 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:55 | step_3 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:50 | step_3 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:45 | step_3 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:40 | step_2 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:35 | step_2 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:30 | step_2 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:10 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:05 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:00 | step_3 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:55 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:50 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:45 | step_2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:40 | step_1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:35 | step_1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:30 | step_1 |

The state I am aiming for would look a bit like this:

| recipe | timestamp | step | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:55 | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:50 | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:45 | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:40 | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:35 | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:30 | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:55 | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:50 | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:45 | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:40 | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:35 | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:30 | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:10 | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:05 | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:00 | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:55 | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:50 | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:45 | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:40 | step_1 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:35 | step_1 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:30 | step_1 | False |

So far, I have managed to generate a new column which shows the difference in seconds between each step, partitioned by recipe / step, using the following code:

```
WITH differences AS (
SELECT
    *,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, lag(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY recipe, step ORDER BY timestamp DESC)) AS difference
FROM recipe_steps
)
```

This results in the following (showing step 1s, for recipe 1, only):

| recipe | timestamp | step | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 | NULL |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:40 | step_1 | 35 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:35 | step_1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:30 | step_1 | 5 |

The idea being that, for a particular recipe, the current / latest execution of the recipe starts at the row **after** the latest row with a difference greater than 5 seconds:

| recipe | timestamp | step | difference | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:25 | step_1 | NULL | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:20 | step_1 | 5 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:56:15 | step_1 | 5 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:40 | step_1 | 35 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:35 | step_1 | 5 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07 21:55:30 | step_1 | 5 | False |

After many hours of research, I am at a total loss as to how to derive the "current" column from the "difference" column, which is the reason for this question.

I've tried various methods of deriving the "current" column from the "difference" column, including the use of `row_number()` and window functions, but without success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) and some match trick to get the result you wants in a few steps:

Step 1. Use window function to calculate the extract row when  a recipe restart, by your definition, that means it's a step 1 row for the recipe and its time difference from previous step is larger than 5 sec.

Step 2: Use windwo function and marked recipe_restart point to get recipe_restart_bucket, since you want to get the result in descending order, we do a math trick to sum(#restart) - sum (#seenrestartsofar) to bucket index in descending order.

Step 3: add current_flag when bucket_index=0 (the most recent one in descending order)

Here is the [query for all steps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f475b/25):

```
with recipe_steps_time_diff AS (
select
    recipe,
    timestamp,
    step,
    case when step <> 'step_1' or datediff(SECOND, lag(timestamp) over(partition by recipe,step order by timestamp), timestamp) <=5 then 0 else 1 end as recipe_restart 
from
   recipe_steps
),
recipe_steps_restart_bucket AS (
select
    recipe,
    timestamp,
    step,
    sum(recipe_restart) over (partition by recipe) - sum(recipe_restart) over (partition by recipe order by timestamp) as recipe_restart_bucket
from
    recipe_steps_time_diff
)
select
    recipe,
    timestamp,
    step,
    case when recipe_restart_bucket = 0 then 'True' else 'False' end as current_flag   
from
    recipe_steps_restart_bucket
order by recipe_restart_bucket, recipe, timestamp desc
```

| recipe | timestamp | step | current_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:55Z | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:50Z | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:45Z | step_3 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:40Z | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:35Z | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:30Z | step_2 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:25Z | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:20Z | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:15Z | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:55Z | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:50Z | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:45Z | step_3 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:40Z | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:35Z | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:30Z | step_2 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:25Z | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:20Z | step_1 | True |
| 2 | 2023-03-07T21:56:15Z | step_1 | True |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:10Z | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:05Z | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:56:00Z | step_3 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:55Z | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:50Z | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:45Z | step_2 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:40Z | step_1 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:35Z | step_1 | False |
| 1 | 2023-03-07T21:55:30Z | step_1 | False |

Comment: This was awesome, thank you. The only thing I had to modify was the handling of NULL steps (which I did not specify as a possibility in my original question). To do this I simply cast NULL steps as "no_step" so that the summation logic could handle these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partitions the rows by recipe and step, and then uses the ROW_NUMBER() window function to assign a number to each row within its partition, ordered by timestamp in descending order

```
  SELECT 
recipe, timestamp, step,
CASE
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recipe, step ORDER BY timestamp DESC) = 1 THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END AS current
```

FROM recipe_steps
ORDER BY recipe, timestamp DESC;

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Comment: Check now please

Answer (score 0):

You were headed in the right direction.

Starting from your difference cte, I assign FALSE to the > 5 timestamps.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN difference > 5 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS firstFalse
  FROM diff
```

Using a self join, I assigned FALSE to every date before the 'firstFalse'. This returns all timestamps that are false.

```
   SELECT f1.recipe,
          f1.step,
          MIN(f2.t_stamp) firstFalse,
          f1.t_stamp,
          'FALSE' AS Curr
     FROM false1 f1
     JOIN false1 f2 ON f1.recipe = f2.recipe AND f1.step = f2.step AND f2.firstFalse = 'FALSE'
    WHERE f1.t_stamp <= f2.t_stamp
 GROUP BY f1.recipe, f1.step, f1.t_stamp
```

Finally I put it all together with a left join.

```
SELECT f1.recipe,
       f1.t_stamp AS [timestamp],
       f1.step,
       COALESCE(f2.curr, 'TRUE') AS [current]  
  FROM false1 f1
  LEFT JOIN false2 f2 ON f1.recipe = f2.recipe AND f1.step = f2.step AND f1.t_stamp = f2.t_stamp 
 ORDER BY [current] desc, f1.recipe asc, f1.step asc, f1.t_stamp asc
```

The whole thing with a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aipeJ-QV?hide=8)

```
WITH diff AS 
  (SELECT recipe,
          t_stamp,
          step,
          DATEDIFF(SECOND, t_stamp, lag(t_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY recipe, step ORDER BY t_stamp DESC)) AS difference
     FROM recipes
  )
, false1 AS
  (SELECT *,
          CASE WHEN difference > 5 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS firstFalse
     FROM diff
  )
, false2 AS
  (
   SELECT f1.recipe,
          f1.step,
          MIN(f2.t_stamp) firstFalse,
          f1.t_stamp,
          'FALSE' AS Curr
     FROM false1 f1
     JOIN false1 f2 ON f1.recipe = f2.recipe AND f1.step = f2.step AND f2.firstFalse = 'FALSE'
    WHERE f1.t_stamp <= f2.t_stamp
 GROUP BY f1.recipe, f1.step, f1.t_stamp
  )
  
SELECT f1.recipe,
       f1.t_stamp AS [timestamp],
       f1.step,
       COALESCE(f2.curr, 'TRUE') AS [current]  
  FROM false1 f1
  LEFT JOIN false2 f2 ON f1.recipe = f2.recipe AND f1.step = f2.step AND f1.t_stamp = f2.t_stamp 
 ORDER BY [current] desc, f1.recipe asc, f1.step asc, f1.t_stamp asc
```